# Angular subscribe in looped children called multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a *ParentComponent* which has a `*ngFor` loop to add *ChildComponent*.
The *ChildComponent* has a *ButtonComponent* which has a button when clicked updates a variable in a `BehaviourSubject`.

The `ngOnInit()` of the *ChildComponent* subscribes to the `BehaviourSubject`.
I expect it to be subscribed only once. But what happens is, if there are 50 *ChildComponents*, the subscription happens 50 times.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**ParentComponent html**

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div *ngFor="let c in count">
    <child-component></child-componet>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ParentComponent ts**

```js
count = [1, 2, 3];
```

**ChildComponent html**

```html
<div class="child">
  <buttons-component></buttons-component>
</div>
```

**ChildComponent ts**

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.service.yourName
    .pipe(distinctUntilChanged(),take(1))
    .subscribe((x) => {
      console.log("hello");
    });
}
```

**ButtonsComponent html**

```html
<div class="button">
  <button (click)="change()">Click</button>
</div>
```

**ButtonComponent ts**

```js
change(): void {
  this.service.changeName("somename");
}
```

**Service file**

```js
private source = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
yourNAme = this.source.asObservable();
    
changeName(message: string) {
  this.source.next(message);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of the code of parent and child components?

Comment: The subscription isn't being called 50 times, the problem is that you are creating 50 subscriptions, one for each child.

Comment: As far as I understand, this behavior is expected. You create as many child components as the number of items in the `count` array within the loop and each one of them subscribes to the service subject. And each one of them subscribes only once (of course if you unsubscribe them in on destroy)

Comment: @HarunYilmaz  say suppose, instead of having a hard coded value that is being set in the behaviour subject, if the button in each row sets a different value. Even in that case, value that I passed is being displayed in the console. Is there a way to prevent calling it 50 times?

Comment: @CaioOliveira but, the same value is being dispalyed in the console, if i chage that from the hardcoded string to a value passed from ButtonsComponent

Comment: You can use `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject` if you don't want to get a default value upon subscription. By using `Subject` you will get the value only after the `.next()` is called but it will still print to the console 50 times on value change.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent printing of 50 times. I need a solution for that

Comment: No way if you print it in the child component. Bu you can move `console.log()` to the `changeName()` method of the service, before calling `.next()`: `console.log(message); this.source.next(message);`

Comment: Also, can you explain, why it is called 50 times?

Comment: When Angular runs the `ngFor` loop, it creates 50 instances of `ChildComponent`, each one is independent and unaware of others. This means 50 different `ngOnInit` method calls occur and they subscribe to the service property. After service passes a value to the subject, each subscriber (child components) prints the message to the console.

Answer (score 1):

You are subscribing in the ngOnInit of child component, so there are 50 subscribes if there are 50 child.

Instead subscribe in the parent component so you only subscribe once.

Put the following in **Parent Component** instead of **Child Component**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.yourName
      .pipe(distinctUntilChanged(),take(1))
      .subscribe((x) => {
        console.log("hello");
      });
   }
```

Comment: What if I need to call a method inside ChildComponent?